# jQuery: Having the smooth scrolling as well as tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to impleemnt smooth scrolling as well as having multiple tabs in the same web page using jQuery/JavaScript. But they don't seem to work together.

HTML:

```
<section>
                <div class="tabs tabs-style-bar">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#section-bar-1"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#section-bar-2"><span>Archive</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#section-bar-3"><span>Analytics</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <div class="content-wrap">
                        <section id="section-bar-1"><p>1</p></section>
                        <section id="section-bar-2"><p>2</p></section>
                        <section id="section-bar-3"><p>3</p></section>
                    </div><!-- /content -->
                </div><!-- /tabs -->
            </section>
```

JavaScript:

For tabs:

```
(function() {

                [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.tabs' ) ).forEach( function( el ) {
                    new CBPFWTabs( el );
                });

            })();
```

and:

```
( function( window ) {

    'use strict';

    function extend( a, b ) {
        for( var key in b ) { 
            if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                a[key] = b[key];
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    function CBPFWTabs( el, options ) {
        this.el = el;
        this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
        extend( this.options, options );
        this._init();
    }

    CBPFWTabs.prototype.options = {
        start : 0
    };

    CBPFWTabs.prototype._init = function() {
        // tabs elems
        this.tabs = [].slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( 'nav > ul > li' ) );
        // content items
        this.items = [].slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( '.content-wrap > section' ) );
        // current index
        this.current = -1;
        // show current content item
        this._show();
        // init events
        this._initEvents();
    };

    CBPFWTabs.prototype._initEvents = function() {
        var self = this;
        this.tabs.forEach( function( tab, idx ) {
            tab.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                self._show( idx );
            } );
        } );
    };

    CBPFWTabs.prototype._show = function( idx ) {
        if( this.current >= 0 ) {
            this.tabs[ this.current ].className = this.items[ this.current ].className = '';
        }
        // change current
        this.current = idx != undefined ? idx : this.options.start >= 0 && this.options.start < this.items.length ? this.options.start : 0;
        this.tabs[ this.current ].className = 'tab-current';
        this.items[ this.current ].className = 'content-current';
    };

    // add to global namespace
    window.CBPFWTabs = CBPFWTabs;

})( window );
```

This is for smooth scroll:

```
$("body").ready(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 800);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

I have been trying for a few days, still not able to fix this. What is this happening and what's the fix?
    });

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to create your own smooth scrolling plugin, why not use one that has already been made by someone which has many, *many*, customizable features.

It's called [NiceScroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/). I use this plugin on my [site](http://joshmurray.eu/).

You will need [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/) to use this, below is an example of how to customize NiceScroll.

```
function scroll() {
    $("html").niceScroll({
        cursorcolor: "#333333",
        cursorborder: "none",
        cursorwidth: "15px",
        background: "#6d6d6d",
        autohidemode: "false",
        horizrailenabled: "false"
    });
}
scroll();
```

Of course, there are a lot more customisable features. If you use the example, make sure you copy that into your `$(document).ready();`.

Comment: I do not like external plugins since they slow down my website and add load onto the client side.

Comment: @QuikProBroNa: But saying that, a lot of external plugins **CAN** be a lot more efficient than custom code. Oh well, it was just a suggestion.